# Passing variables to child component doesn't update reactively when dragging parent

Tags: javascript, svelte

I have a component ("Mover.svelte") that's responsible for providing mouse-drag functionality to whatever component is in its  ("Button.svelte" in this case.)

I'm trying to display the current X/Y position in the child object, which works, but doesn't update reactively as the object moves. (There's no error message, just not working as expected.)

I have tried a variety of ways to do this, including Svelte's context API, but none of the approaches I've tried seem to enable the reactivity.

REPL:
https://svelte.dev/repl/1d2b72dbf8aa465fa60b76f2e93fb0cc?version=3.49.0

app.svelte:

```
<script>
    import Mover from "./Mover.svelte";
    import Button from "./Button.svelte";
</script>

<Mover>
        <Button />
</Mover>
```

Mover.svelte:

```
<script>
    
    import { setContext } from 'svelte';

    let moving = false;
    export let x = 120;
    export let y = 130;
    
    setContext('x', x);
    setContext('y', y);

    function dragItem(e) {
        if (moving) {
            x += e.movementX;
            y += e.movementY;
        }
    }
    
</script>

<div on:mousedown={() => moving = true} on:mouseup={() => moving = false} style="left: {x}px; top: {y}px;">
    <slot />
</div>

<svelte:window on:mousemove={dragItem} />

<style>
    div {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        position: absolute;
        border: 4px solid green;
    }
</style>
```

Button.svelte:

```
<script>
    import { getContext } from 'svelte';
    
    let x = getContext('x')
    let y = getContext('y')
    
</script>
    

<button>
    X/Y should update on drag:
    {x}, {y}
</button>
    

<style>
    button {
        border: 4px solid blue;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 12;
    }
</style>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a context, you have to use a store, as setting/getting the context is a one-time operation. Reactivity does not transfer between files except through props; stores can bridge that gap.

E.g. in Mover:

```js
import { setContext } from 'svelte';
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';

let moving = false;
export let x = 120;
export let y = 130;

const xStore = setContext('x', writable(x));
const yStore = setContext('y', writable(y));

// Synch the stores on change:
$: $xStore = x;
$: $yStore = y;
```

In Button add `$` prefix to read from the stores:

```html
<button>
    X/Y should update on drag:
    {$x}, {$y}
</button>
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/076be0044f0345ab8a494ceb5cb9e834?version=3.49.0)

---

As alternative to contexts, using [slot props](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-slot-slot-key-value) would also be possible here.

In mover set the props on the slot:

```html
<slot {x} {y} />
```

Pass them down in App:

```html
<Mover let:x let:y>
        <Button {x} {y} />
</Mover>
```

(Button then needs to declare props for `x`/`y`)

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/4e303555d4d146d6b79c758da16b0205?version=3.49.0)